# How to find out what distro i'm using on go daddy shared host ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

i've purchased a go daddy web host (Linux Deluxe with cpanel) and i'm using SSH with Putty, i logged into the server and hit "sudo su" and i got this:

```
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

then, i hit "uname -a", got this:

```
Linux myserver 2.6.32-673.26.1.lve1.4.18.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 21 11:58:14 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

but "Linux" is too generic, how can i know what distro is that? and use sudo...

sorry for bad english

Answer (score 9):

try this

```
lsb_release -a
```

if there is not this command, try

```
cat /proc/version
```

maybe useful. not work in coreos

Comment: -bash: lsb_release: command not found :/

Comment: try cat /proc/version

Comment: Linux version 2.6.32-673.26.1.lve1.4.18.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@build.cloudlinux.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Oct 21 11:58:14 EDT 2016

Comment: so its Red Hat? how can i use sudo?

Comment: my centos6.8 output is 
Linux version 2.6.32-642.6.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@worker1.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Oct 5 00:36:12 UTC 2016

Comment: but it does not work centos commands.

Comment: cat /proc/version worked for my redhat

Comment: `cat /proc/version` is better than `uname -a` (the latter didn't reveal that it was redhat, even though the outputs look similar).

Answer (score 1):

I use something I distilled from from [easy server Install](https://github.com/coto/server-easy-install/blob/master/lib/core.sh)

see [ShootProfile.sh @ GitLab](https://gitlab.com/snippets/33722) for the source and use as:

```
curl -sL https://gitlab.com/snippets/33722/raw | bash
```

and produces an output like f.i a CentOS7 VM:

```
OS: linux
DIST: CentOS Linux
PSUEDONAME: Core 
REV: 7.3.1611
DistroBasedOn: redhat
KERNEL: 3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64
MACH: x86_64
========
```

Comment: Mine says `DIST   : BusyBox` though `cat /proc/version` shows Redhat. Thanks still.